# Get user Geolocation when user uses modem

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, geolocation

I have an application that detect user's positions, uses geolocation and show it in map (google maps API)

The application work properly when user using wifi, it show user's current positions but if the user using modem,the application show isp's (Internet service provider) position not the current user's position...

How i can solved this? anysolutions?
thanks before..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but it's not possible to get 100% guaranteed result.  BTW, when the user is connected via Wifi you are potentially detecting the location of the cell phone tower and/or upstream provider, but in your test case it may just happen to be in the nearby vicinity so it appears to be working, whereas with the modem it communicates all the way back to the phone provider which is clearly not nearby.

The best you can do is check the accuracy of the geocoordinates you are receiving and provide a message to the user instructing them to ensure their hardware GPS is enabled.  The operating system receives the request for geo-location and depending on user settings it will determine geo-location using ISP, WIFI, or true GPS.  Best of luck.